# Using crate notify in async environment

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using crate notify to watch for file changes.
My problem is, that I use it in an asynchronous environment. Today I realized, that my "notify" thread is using 100% CPU...

I would need help in a sample, how to use this sync-crate in an async world.

I spawn a new async thread and run a loop inside. In the loop I check, if a new notification is available and afterwards yield to enable other async tasks to run.

And exactly here I consume 100% of CPU. How to do this correct?
In my opinion a blocking recv() is not possible because I want to react on CTRL-C.
Do I need a sleep instead of yield?

```
tokio::select! {
    _ = async {
        loop {
            if let Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(path)) = watcher_rx.try_recv() {
                process_create(path).await;
            }
            actix_rt::task::yield_now().await;
        }
    } => {},
    _ = actix_rt::signal::ctrl_c() => {},
}
```

---

I refactored my code and created a wrapper around notify crate. I integrated the ideas from @stepan.
But in spawn_blocking I can't use an async function. Because I need this in an async environment, I use an async channel...

```
mod mywatcher {
    use async_std::path::Path;
    use notify::Error;
    use std::sync::Arc;
    use std::time::Duration;
    use tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender;
    use tokio::sync::Mutex;

    pub use notify::DebouncedEvent;
    pub use notify::RecursiveMode;

    pub async fn watcher(tx: Sender<DebouncedEvent>, delay: Duration) -> Result<MyWatcher, Error> {
        let (notify_tx, notify_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
        let notify = notify::watcher(notify_tx, delay)?;

        tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || async {
            process_changes(Arc::new(Mutex::new(notify_rx)), tx).await
        })
        .await
        .unwrap();

        Ok(MyWatcher { notify })
    }

    async fn process_changes(
        notify_rx: Arc<Mutex<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<DebouncedEvent>>>,
        watcher_tx: Sender<DebouncedEvent>,
    ) {
        println!("Process Changes");
        loop {
            println!("In loop and waiting...");
            let rx = notify_rx.lock().await;
            let event = rx.recv();
            if event.is_err() {
                return;
            }

            let event = event.unwrap();
            println!("EVENT {:?}", event);
            watcher_tx.send(event).await.unwrap();
        }
    }

    pub struct MyWatcher {
        notify: notify::FsEventWatcher,
    }

    impl MyWatcher {
        pub async fn watch<P: AsRef<Path>>(
            &mut self,
            p: P,
            recursive_mode: RecursiveMode,
        ) -> Result<(), Error> {
            use notify::Watcher;
            self.notify.watch(p.as_ref(), recursive_mode)
        }

        pub async fn unwatch<P: AsRef<Path>>(&mut self, p: P) -> Result<(), Error> {
            use notify::Watcher;
            self.notify.unwatch(p.as_ref())
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use mywatcher::RecursiveMode;
    use std::time::Duration;
    use tokio::sync::mpsc;

    let (watcher_tx, watcher_rx) = mpsc::channel(10);
    let mut watcher = mywatcher::watcher(watcher_tx, Duration::from_secs(10))
        .await
        .expect("create watcher failed");

    watcher
        .watch(
            "/Develope/async-notify",
            RecursiveMode::NonRecursive,
        )
        .await
        .expect("watch failed");

    for i in 1..30 {
        println!("waiting...");
        tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }

    watcher
        .unwatch("/Develope/async-notify")
        .await
        .expect("unwatch failed");
}
```

Cargo.toml Dependencies:

```
tokio = { version = "1", features = [
    "macros",
    "rt-multi-thread",
    "sync",
    "time",
] }
notify = "4.0.17"
async-std = "1.10.0"
```

Comment: Don't use `try_recv`, instead use `recv` which will block the current thread until there is a notification to process.

Comment: Yes, but this would block the whole async processing. Hence I did the `try_recv`. The crate is not async... But I try now the suggestion from @stepan below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate task for notify as one of possible solutions. `select` is not needed in that case:

```
tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
  loop {
    if let Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(path)) = rx.recv() {
       tokio::spawn(process_create(path));
    } else {
       break;
    }
  }
});

actix_rt::signal::ctrl_c().await;
```

If "process_create" can't be directly called in that place (e.g. there's more data in the actual app that isn't allowing it to be called), another option to consider is using a second channel (tokio mspc for example) and relay messages through that channel.

Comment: Problem: rx is created outside of spawn_blocking; I'll get a compile error: `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<notify::DebouncedEvent>` cannot be shared between threads safely
the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<notify::DebouncedEvent>`

Comment: "move" keyword should have told the compiler to move ownership of the Receiver into the task. Check if you're referencing your Receiver somewhere after spawning the task - you will have to change that usage (or remove it) or wrap receiver into an Arc+Mutex.

Comment: @macalloy right, makes sense. Try "async move" (I updated the post to reflect that).  It compiles for me.

Comment: yes, it compiles. But the async block (in spawn_blocking) is not awaited. Hence nothing is executed.

Comment: @macalloy you are correct, I missed that. I've updated the code with another suggestion.

Comment: it works! But why? Tokio start its runtime in its own system thread. With spawn_blocking a new system thread is started. And this thread has - via `tokio::spawn` - again access to the async-runtime of the system tokio thread ?!? Can you explain this?

Comment: @macalloy spawn_blocking starts a thread that still has access to the same runtime handle that started it, so if you call tokio::spawn it'll just work the same way it normally does